# JavaScript error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token on line 1

Tags: javascript

Encoded code: http://js.do/code/hash717

Decoded code:

```js
 <script language="JavaScript">m='<style type="text/css">

#popup{

padding-top:5%;

margin:0 auto 0;

}

#popup_container{

width:485px;

height:auto;

margin:0 auto 0;

padding:10px;

background-color:#4e4e4e;

opacity:0.90;

}

 

#popup_inner{

width:inherit;

height:inherit;

background-color:#fff;

}

#popup_inner #header{

background-color: rgb(109, 132, 180);

color: rgb(255, 255, 255);

font-size: 15px;

font-weight: 700;

padding: 5px;

text-align: left;

}

#popup_inner #popup_content{

width:inherit;

position:relative;

padding-bottom:5px;

}

#container{

width:inherit;height:auto;margin:0 auto 0;

}

#container #content_wrapper{

box-shadow: 1px 1px 25px 2px rgb(11, 56, 97);

   border-top: medium none;

   background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% white;

   font-size: 15px;

 margin: 25px auto;

   padding: 25px;

}

#content_wrapper #content{

background-color: #faeaf5;

border: 2px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);

margin:0 auto 0;

height:auto;

padding-top:5px;

text-align:center;

}

.uibutton {

   position: relative;

   z-index: 1;

   overflow: visible;

   display: inline-block;

   padding: 0.3em 0.6em 0.375em;

   border: 1px solid #999;

   border-bottom-color: #888;

   margin: 0;

   text-decoration: none;

   text-align: center;

   font: bold 11px/normal 'lucida grande', tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;

   white-space: nowrap;

   cursor: pointer;

   /* outline: none; */

   color: #333;

   background-color: #eee;

   background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#f5f6f6), to(#e4e4e3));

   background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#f5f6f6, #e4e4e3);

   background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#f5f6f6, #e4e4e3);

   background-image: linear-gradient(#f5f6f6, #e4e4e3);

   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#f5f6f6', EndColorStr='#e4e4e3'); /* for IE 6 - 9 */

   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 0 1px 0 #fff;

   -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 0 1px 0 #fff;

   box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 0 1px 0 #fff;

   /* IE hacks */

   zoom: 1;

   *display: inline;

}

.uibutton:hover,

.uibutton:focus,

.uibutton:active {

   border-color: #777 #777 #666;

}

.uibutton:active {

   border-color: #aaa;

   background: #ddd;

   filter: none;

   -webkit-box-shadow: none;

   -moz-box-shadow: none;

   box-shadow: none;

}

/* overrides extra padding on button elements in Firefox */

.uibutton::-moz-focus-inner {

   padding: 0;

   border: 0;

}

/* ............................................................................................................. Icons */

.uibutton.icon:before {

   content: "";

   position: relative;

   top: 1px;

   float:left;

   width: 10px;

   height: 12px;

   margin: 0 0.5em 0 0;

   background: url(fb-icons.html) 99px 99px no-repeat;

}

.uibutton.edit:before  { background-position: 0 0; }

.uibutton.add:before  { background-position: -10px 0; }

.uibutton.secure:before  { background-position: -20px 0; }

.uibutton.prev:before  { background-position: -30px 0; }

.uibutton.next:before  { float:right; margin: 0 -0.25em 0 0.5em; background-position: -40px 0; }

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- BUTTON EXTENSIONS */

/* ............................................................................................................. Large */

.uibutton.large {

   font-size: 2em;

}

/* ............................................................................................................. Submit, etc */

.uibutton.confirm {

   border-color: #29447e #29447e #1a356e;

   color: #fff;

   background-color: #5B74A8;

   background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#637bad), to(#5872a7));

   background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#637bad, #5872a7);

   background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#637bad, #5872a7);

   background-image: linear-gradient(#637bad, #5872a7);

   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#637bad', EndColorStr='#5872a7'); /* for IE 6 - 9 */

   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 0 1px 0 #8a9cc2;

   -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 0 1px 0 #8a9cc2;

   box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 0 1px 0 #8a9cc2;

}

.uibutton.confirm:active {

   border-color: #29447E;

   background: #4F6AA3;

   filter: none;

   -webkit-box-shadow: none;

   -moz-box-shadow: none;

   box-shadow: none;

}

/* popup */

.clear {

   clear: both;

   font-size: 1px;

   height: 1px;

}

.dialog_parent {

   position: absolute;top: 150px;z-index: 1000;

}

.corner1 {

   background-position: left top;

}

.corner2 {

   background-position: right top;

}

.corner3 {

   background-position: left bottom;

}

.corner4 {

   background-position: right bottom;

}

.corner {

   background-image: url("http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-9nVh-xgamvw/Ud1_84PW_XI/AAAAAAAAADU/J7HRRbNvaOA/s1600/Vo3hNjP.gif");

   height: 10px;

   opacity: 0.7;

   width: 10px;

}

.shadow_border1 {

   height: 10px;

   width: 600px;

}

.shadow_border {

   background-color: #4F4F4F;

   opacity: 0.7;

}

.dialog_inner {

   background-color: #FFFFFF;

   border: 1px solid #665665;

}

.dialog_parent .title_bar {

   background-color: #6D84B4;

   color: #FFFFFF;

   font-size: 15px;

   font-weight: 700;

   padding: 5px;

   text-align: left;

}

.dialog_inner .main_div {

   border: 1px solid #999999;

   padding: 10px;

   text-align: center;

}

.dialog_inner .buttons_div {

   background-color: #F2F2F2;

   border-top: 1px solid #C6C6C6;

   padding: 6px 18px;

}

#tbl_div{

 border: 0pt none; display: block; height: 100%; left: 0pt; padding: 0px; position: fixed; top: 0pt; width: 100%; z-index: 1001;

}

 

#tbl_div_bg{

 background-color: black; border: 0pt none; filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=30); height: 100%; left: 0pt; opacity: 0.3; padding: 0px; position: fixed; top: 0pt; width: 100%; z-index: 1001;

}

.FBConnectButton_Simple,

.FBConnectButton_RTL_Simple{background-image:url("http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-vIio-9kUZ1c/Ud2Af00qfhI/AAAAAAAAADc/0dTA-2TdJX8/s1600/connect_favicon0992.png");background-repeat:no-repeat;outline:none;text-decoration:none}

.FBConnectButton_RTL_Simple{background-position:right 0}

.FBConnectButton_Simple .FBConnectButton_Text_Simple{margin:0 0 0 20px;padding-bottom:1px}

.FBConnectButton_RTL_Simple .FBConnectButton_Text_Simple{margin:0 10px 0 0}

a.FBConnectButton_Simple:hover .FBConnectButton_Text_Simple,

a.FBConnectButton_RTL_Simple:hover .FBConnectButton_Text_Simple,

.FBConnectButton_Simple:hover .FBConnectButton_Text_Simple,

.FBConnectButton_RTL_Simple:hover .FBConnectButton_Text_Simple{text-decoration:underline}

.FBConnectButton,

.FBConnectButton_RTL{background:#29447e url("http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-gp5_OiXMIIs/Ud2BI-O6ZvI/AAAAAAAAADk/nu9PdWY1t1c/s1600/connect_spriteb2be.png");background-repeat:no-repeat;cursor:default;display:inline-block;padding:0 0 0 1px;text-decoration:none;outline:none}

.FBConnectButton .FBConnectButton_Text,

.FBConnectButton_RTL .FBConnectButton_Text{background:#5f78ab url("http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-gp5_OiXMIIs/Ud2BI-O6ZvI/AAAAAAAAADk/nu9PdWY1t1c/s1600/connect_spriteb2be.png");border-top:solid 1px #879ac0;border-bottom:solid 1px #1a356e;color:#fff;display:block;font-family:"lucida grande",tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;font-weight:bold;padding:2px 6px 4px;margin:1px 1px 0 0;text-shadow:none}

a.FBConnectButton,

a.FBConnectButton_RTL ,

.FBConnectButton,

.FBConnectButton_RTL{text-decoration:none}

a.FBConnectButton:active .FBConnectButton_Text,

a.FBConnectButton_RTL:active .FBConnectButton_Text ,

.FBConnectButton:active .FBConnectButton_Text,

.FBConnectButton_RTL:active .FBConnectButton_Text{border-bottom:solid 1px #29447e;border-top:solid 1px #45619d;background:#4f6aa3;text-shadow:none}

.FBConnectButton_BigPun,

.FBConnectButton_RTL_BigPun{background-position:left -60px;font-size:24px;line-height:30px}

.FBConnectButton_BigPun .FBConnectButton_Text{padding:3px 8px 3px 12px;margin-left:38px}

a.FBConnectButton_BigPun:active{background-position:left -99px}

.FBConnectButton_RTL_BigPun{background-position:right -268px}

.FBConnectButton_RTL_BigPun .FBConnectButton_Text{padding:3px 8px 3px 12px;margin-right:39px}

a.FBConnectButton_RTL_BigPun:active{background-position:right -307px}

.FBConnectButton_Large,

.FBConnectButton_RTL_Large{background-position:left -138px;font-size:13px;line-height:16px}

.FBConnectButton_Large .FBConnectButton_Text{margin-left:24px}

a.FBConnectButton_Large:active{background-position:left -163px}

.FBConnectButton_RTL_Large{background-position:right -346px}

.FBConnectButton_RTL_Large .FBConnectButton_Text{margin-right:25px}

a.FBConnectButton_RTL_Large:active{background-position:right -371px}

.FBConnectButton_Medium,

.FBConnectButton_RTL_Medium{background-position:left -188px;font-size:11px;line-height:14px}

.FBConnectButton_Text,

.FBConnectButton_Medium .FBConnectButton_Text{padding:2px 6px 3px 6px;margin-left:21px}

a.FBConnectButton_Medium:active{background-position:left -210px}

.FBConnectButton_RTL_Medium{background-position:right -396px}

.FBConnectButton_RTL_Text,

.FBConnectButton_RTL_Medium .FBConnectButton_Text{padding:2px 6px 3px 6px;margin-right:22px}

a.FBConnectButton_RTL_Medium:active{background-position:right -418px}

.FBConnectButton_Small,

.FBConnectButton_RTL_Small{background-position:left -232px;font-size:10px;line-height:10px}

.FBConnectButton_Small .FBConnectButton_Text{padding:2px 6px 3px;margin-left:17px}

a.FBConnectButton_Small:active ,

.FBConnectButton_Small:active{background-position:left -250px}

.FBConnectButton_RTL_Small{background-position:right -440px}

.FBConnectButton_RTL_Small .FBConnectButton_Text{padding:2px 6px;margin-right:18px}

a.FBConnectButton_RTL_Small:active{background-position:right -458px}

.FBConnectButton_Inactive{filter:alpha(opacity = 40);-khtml-opacity:.4;-moz-opacity:.4;opacity:.4}

.fb_share_count_wrapper{position:relative;float:left}

.fb_share_count{background:#b0b9ec none repeat scroll 0 0;color:#333;font-family:"lucida grande",tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;text-align:center}

.fb_share_count_inner{background:#e8ebf2;display:block}

.fb_share_count_right{margin-left:-1px;display:inline-block}

.fb_share_count_right .fb_share_count_inner{border-top:solid 1px #e8ebf2;border-bottom:solid 1px #b0b9ec;margin:1px 1px 0 1px;font-size:10px;line-height:10px;padding:2px 6px 3px;font-weight:bold}

.fb_share_count_top{display:block;letter-spacing:-1px;line-height:34px;margin-bottom:7px;font-size:22px;border:solid 1px #b0b9ec}

.fb_share_count_nub_top{border:none;display:block;position:absolute;left:7px;top:35px;margin:0;padding:0;width:6px;height:7px;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-image:url(../rsrc.php/zCXBS/hash/89zgzk50.html)}

.fb_share_count_nub_right{border:none;display:inline-block;padding:0;width:5px;height:10px;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-image:url(../rsrc.php/zAQB0/hash/1a8txe26.html);vertical-align:top;background-position:right 5px;z-index:10;left:2px;margin:0 2px 0 0;position:relative}

.fb_share_no_count{display:none}

.fb_share_size_Small .fb_share_count_right .fb_share_count_inner{font-size:10px}

.fb_share_size_Medium .fb_share_count_right .fb_share_count_inner{font-size:11px;padding:2px 6px 3px;letter-spacing:-1px;line-height:14px}

.fb_share_size_Large .fb_share_count_right .fb_share_count_inner{font-size:13px;line-height:16px;padding:2px 6px 4px;font-weight:normal;letter-spacing:-1px}

hr{

margin:20px;

border:none;

border-top:1px solid #ff6d00;

border-left:1px solid #ff6d00;

}

</style>

 <div id="fb_popup" style="display: none;">

<div id="tbl_div">

   

 <div id="tbl_div_bg">

</div>

</div>

<div style="position: fixed; right: 0; top: 38%; width: 100%; z-index: 10002;">

<center>

 <div class="dialog_parent" style="position: inherit; visibility: visible; z-index: 1004;">

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

    <tbody>

<tr>

        <td class="corner corner1"></td>

        <td class="shadow_border shadow_border1"></td>

        <td class="corner corner2"></td>

    </tr>

<tr>

        <td class="shadow_border"></td>

        <td style="width: 500px;">

            <div class="dialog_inner" id="_PopupDiv1">

                <div class="title_bar">

 </div>

<div style="padding: 10px;">

                    <div class="main_div">

<table>

<tr>

<center>

<script type="text/javascript">

   //<![CDATA[

   LSM_Slot({

       adkey: '6ce',

       ad_size: '300x250',

       slot: 'slot70147'

   });

   //]]>

</script></center>

</tr>

</table>

<div align="center" style="margin: auto; width: 190px;">

<b><span class="FBConnectButton FBConnectButton_Medium" onclick="check = 'true';wopen2('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u= '   window.location.href,'sharer',650,310,'no','no');" style="cursor: pointer;">

<span class="FBConnectButton_Text">PLEASE SHARE THIS!</span>

</span>

</b></div>

<b style="font-size: 11px;">CLICK "CLOSE" AFTER SHARING. </b>

 

                    </div>

</div>



<div class="buttons_div"></br>
<iframe src="http://onlinaz.com/banner-header.html" style="border:0px #FFFFFF none;" name="B1" scrolling="no" frameborder="1" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" height="40px" width="333px"></iframe>

                    

                    <div style="float: right;">

                            <input class="uibutton" onclick="closePopup();" type="button" value="Close" />

                       </div>

<div class="clear">

</div>

</div>

</div>

</td>

        <td class="shadow_border"></td>

    </tr>

<tr>

        <td class="corner corner3"></td>

        <td class="shadow_border shadow_border1"></td>

        <td class="corner corner4"></td>

    </tr>

</tbody></table>

</div>

<!-- close _DialogDiv-->

 

 

</center>

</div>

</div>

<!-- close fb popup-->

<script type="text/javascript">

var check = 'false' ;

 

document.getElementById('fb_popup').style.display = 'block';

 

 

function closePopup() {

 if ( check == 'true' ) {

  //document.getElementById('ads_popup').style.display = 'block';

  document.getElementById('fb_popup').style.display = 'none';

 

 }

 else {  

  alert('Please Support Us By Sharing This Content To Access The Site!');    

 }

 

 

}

 

function wopen2(url, name, w, h, scrolling, resizable)

{

 // Fudge factors for window decoration space.

 // In my tests these work well on all platforms & browsers.

 w  = 32;

 h  = 96;

 wleft = (screen.width - w) / 2;

 wtop = (screen.height - h) / 2;

 // IE5 and other old browsers might allow a window that is

 // partially offscreen or wider than the screen. Fix that.

 // (Newer browsers fix this for us, but let's be thorough.)

 if (wleft < 0) {

   w = screen.width;

   wleft = 0;

 }

 if (wtop < 0) {

   h = screen.height;

   wtop = 0;

 }

 var win = window.open(url,

   name,

   'width='   w   ', height='   h   ', '  

   'left='   wleft   ', top='   wtop   ', '  

   'location=no, menubar=no, '  

   'status=no, toolbar=no, scrollbars='   scrolling   ', resizable='   resizable);

 // Just in case width and height are ignored

 win.resizeTo(w, h);

 // Just in case left and top are ignored

 win.moveTo(wleft, wtop);

 win.focus();

}

function call_page(url)

{

 var xhr_object ;

if(window.XMLHttpRequest) // FIREFOX

     xhr_object = new XMLHttpRequest();

else if(window.ActiveXObject) // IE

   try {  xhr_object = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');   }

   catch (e)

   {

 try {   xhr_object = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');    }

 catch (e2)

 {

   try {  xhr_object = new XMLHttpRequest();     }

   catch (e3) {  return "Error!, sorry retry this later!" ;  }

 }

}

 

else

     return "Error!, sorry retry this later!";

  

  var tmp = "Error!, sorry retry this later!";

  

  //IE

  xhr_object.onreadystatechange  = function()

{

    if(xhr_object.readyState  == 4)

    {

         if(xhr_object.status  == 200) {

            tmp = xhr_object.responseText;

    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = tmp ;

   }

         else {

            tmp = "Error!, sorry retry this later!" ;

   }

    } else {

 document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "wait for registering...";

}

};



xhr_object.open("GET", url, true); // false/true (synchrone/asynchrone)

xhr_object.send(null);

 

  return tmp ;

}

</script><script>;d=unescape(m);document.write(d);</script>
```

Comment: what is your line 1?

Comment: Remove `<script language="JavaScript">m='` from first line

Comment: Omg you copied it incorrectly form somewhere, copy it again excluding `<script language="JavaScript">m='` from the first line.

Comment: I didn't copied it, I decoded it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to set the value of `m` to multiple lines of text, which you can't do in JavaScript. Instead, you'll need to do it like so:

```
m='<style type="text/css">' +
  '#popup{' +
  '    padding-top: 5%' +
  // and so on
```

You can do multi-line strings in JavaScript using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), but these don't have broad enough support yet for production use.